# Texmaker: Why is most of the interface so tiny?

Tags: texmaker

I have recently installed Texmaker 4.5 on my new Win10 13.3" screen new laptop and I have founded that it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

I have not been able to fix this, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you can increase e.g. the fontsize in the settings, which may is helpful. Additionally, can you describe precisely what you mean by "interface" ?

Comment: Do you mean the grey area on the right which is reserved for the pdf viewer?

Comment: No, I mean the font on the dark-grey areas, the size of most of the buttons and that stuff. I hope you understand. The only font I have been able to change is the editor's area one (where ''Hello world'' is written). I guess it may be something related with the resolution of the screen (3000x1800) and the 13.3" screen.

Comment: @S.. Well, does it solve your problem when you reduce your screen resolution?

Comment: No, it doesn't solve it. I have no idea

Comment: I'm having the same problem with TeXstudio also